# Change object value to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having JSON object as follow:

```
testUser3: "{"accountDetails":"false"}"
```

I want this object to change to

```
accountDetails: ["false"]
```

I used `$.each`

```
$.each(value, function(key,value){
            this.data = value;
        });
```

but again for this i have to iterate again which i don't want. something like below

```
//for (var i in this.data) {
          //  anarray.push(this.data[i]));
         //
```

Is there any single liner which content the value to array.

Comment: perhaps testUser3["accountDetails"] = [false] ?

Comment: This is quite unclear. Looks like you just want to wrap the value of your JSON object in an array, don't you?

Comment: Is `testUser3` a key inside of another object?

Comment: yes, i want "accountDetails":"false" object value which is false into array

Comment: If you want to convert your json to array/object, you can use JSON.parse method https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the value in an array.

```
object.testUser3.accountDetails = [object.testUser3.accountDetails];
```

```js
var object = { testUser1: { accountDetails: true } , testUser3: { accountDetails: false } };

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (a) {
    object[a] = Object.keys(object[a]).map(function (b) {
        return [object[a][b]];
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that you ment this:var yourObj = {testUser3:

```
{"accountDetails":"false"}};
var newObj = {
    testUser3: {}
};

for(var key in yourObj.testUser3) {
  newObj.testUser3[key] = [yourObj.testUser3[key]];
}
JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

Good luck

> edited code on bases of comments

Comment: thanks for ur help. but data is dynamic and key can be changed. so in this [a[key].accountDetails] accountDetails is dynamic

Comment: So each key under the `testUser3` key would need to become an Array?

Comment: no. just the value of value of testuser3 needs to be array